# jQuery clone form increment all attributes of name,class,id,data-id ..etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function, clone

Our form contain multiple fields and we need to do by jQuery

- when cloning fields need increase it's Name, Class, Id,data-id and label for .

How increase IDs like these

block-post-order-1-select

Or names like this

name="xform_demo[block-post-order-1]

You can check this form code
at codepen http://codepen.io/earngate/pen/NxPOZz/

HTML

```
    <table id="section-table-section-start1" data-id="section-start1" class="form-table form-table-section no-border form-table-section-indented">
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">
    <div class="xform_field_th">
    Block</div>
    </th>
    <td>
    <fieldset id="xform_demo-switch-fold-1" class=" xform-container-switch" data-id="switch-fold-1" data-type="switch">
    <div class="switch-options">
    <label class="cb-enable selected" data-id="switch-fold-1"><span>On</span></label>
    <label class="cb-disable" data-id="switch-fold-1"><span>Off</span></label>
    <input class="checkbox checkbox-input" id="switch-fold-1" name="xform_demo[switch-fold-1]" value="1" type="hidden"></div>
    </fieldset></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fold">
    <th scope="row">
    <div class="xform_field_th">
    Text logo</div>
    </th>
    <td>
    <fieldset id="xform_demo-block-cat-title-1" class="xform-container-text " data-id="block-cat-title-1" data-type="text">
    <input id="block-cat-title-1" name="xform_demo[block-cat-title-1]" value class="regular-text " type="text" size="20"></fieldset></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fold">
    <th scope="row">
    <div class="xform_field_th">
    </div>
    </th>
    <td>
    <fieldset id="xform_demo-block-post-order-1" class=" xform-container-select" data-id="block-post-order-1" data-type="select">
    <div style="width: 40%;" id="s2id_block-post-order-1-select" class="select2-container xform-select-item select2-allowclear">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">
    <span id="select2-chosen-2" class="select2-chosen">first-choise</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>
    <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation">
    </b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen2" class="select2-offscreen">
    </label>
    <input id="s2id_autogen2" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-2" class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" type="text" size="20">
    <div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox">
    <div class="select2-search">
    <label for="s2id_autogen2_search" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
    <input placeholder id="s2id_autogen2_search" aria-owns="select2-results-2" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input"  type="text" size="20">
    </div>
    <ul id="select2-results-2" class="select2-results" role="listbox">
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <select title tabindex="-1" id="block-post-order-1-select" name="xform_demo[block-post-order-1]" class="xform-select-item " style="width: 40%; display: none;" rows="6">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Desc" selected="selected">Lates</option>
    <option value="rand">Random Posts</option>
    </select></fieldset></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-bottom: medium none;" class="compiler fold">
    <th scope="row">
    <div class="xform_field_th">
    Block Style</div>
    </th>
    <td>
    <fieldset id="xform_demo-block_type_1" class=" xform-container-image_select" data-id="block_type_1" data-type="image_select">
    <div class="xform-table-container">
    <ul class="xform-image-select">
    <li class="xform-image-select">
    <label class=" xform-image-select-selected xform-image-select block_type_1_1" for="block_type_1_1">
    <input class=" compiler noUpdate " id="block_type_1_1" name="xform_demo[block_type_1]" value="node" checked="checked" type="radio"><img src="1-3.png" alt="node" class style=" width: 100%; "></label></li>
    <li class="xform-image-select">
    <label class=" xform-image-select block_type_1_2" for="block_type_1_2">
    <input class=" compiler noUpdate  noUpdate " id="block_type_1_2" name="xform_demo[block_type_1]" value="nodey" type="radio"><img src="1-4.png" alt="nodey" class style=" width: 100%; "></label></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </fieldset></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none;" class="xform-section-indent-start">
    <th scope="row"></th>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('table#section-table-section-start1').after('<input class="add_btn" id="add_btn" type="button" value="Add New">');

    $(".add_btn").click(function(e) {
    var avails = $(this).prevAll();
    var cnt = avails.length + 1;

    $('#section-table-section-start1:last').clone().insertAfter("#section-table-section-start1:last").append( $('<input class="del_btn"  type="button" value="Delete this">') );

    $("input.del_btn").css({"float":"right","background-color":"#c00","color":"#fff"});

    e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("body").on('click',".del_btn", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    });
```

Can you help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/tour, especially the section about "practical, detailed questions".  Make an attempt to solve your problem, and we'll help you out with solutions to problems that you run into on the way.  Good luck!

Comment: @MarcL.  Thanks, and we edit full code to add jquery for clone form but still need code to increase name data-id id and classes, Can you help

Comment: Thanks for including your code. I would fallback to a MVVM framework like Knockout.js for this, which may be overkill for your solution.

Comment: @MarcL. Not at all, I hope to help

Comment: Did you try wrapping each copy of your cloned content in a div and checking the length of the class used on the div?

Answer (score 4):

So the question seems to be "how to increase the number in multiple attributes of multiple nodes."
I will narrow it down to increasing the *last* integer in multiple attributes, to keep it simple.

You can create a simple function to increase the number of one attribute of one node, then repeat it for the elements and attributes you need:

```
/* Increase the last number for an attribute of an jQuery element, if possible */
function inc ( node, property ) { // .prop does not work with data-id so must use .attr
   var number = node.attr( property ) ? node.attr( property ).match( /\d+(?=\D*$)/ ) : null;
   if ( number === null ) return; // Abort if has no attribute or no number in it
   node.attr( property, node.attr( property ).replace( /\d+(?=\D*$)/, +number[0]+1 ) );
}

var last = $('[id^=section-table-section-start]:last'), cloned = last.clone();

// For each element with any attribute we need, including the cloned table
cloned.find( '[name],[class],[id],[data-id],[for]' ).add( cloned ).each( function(){
   var me = $( this );
   // Loop and increment each property
   $.each( [ 'name', 'className', 'id', 'data-id', 'for' ], function( i, property ) { 
      inc( me, property );
   });
});
```

There are a few ways to do the loop.

- Here we grab all elements and loop each property on each of them.
- If you have less properties you can manually call `inc` for each property instead of `$.each`.
- Alternatively you may loop each property first and find the elements, this way you create more jQ objects but check less properties.

You may also notice that I changed your clone code, because with the auto-increasing id you can't pick the last table by id any more.

Here is the full code:

```js
$( function () {
   function inc ( element, property ) {
      var number = element.attr( property ) ? element.attr( property ).match( /\d+(?=\D*$)/ ) : null;
      if ( number === null ) return;
      element.attr( property, element.attr( property ).replace( /\d+(?=\D*$)/, +number[0]+1 ) );
   }

   $('table#section-table-section-start1').after('<input class="add_btn" id="add_btn" type="button" value="Add New">');

   $(".add_btn").click(function(e) {
      var last = $('[id^=section-table-section-start]:last'), cloned = last.clone();
      cloned.find( '[name],[class],[id],[data-id],[for]' ).add( cloned ).each( function(){
         var me = $( this );
         $.each( [ 'name', 'className', 'id', 'data-id', 'for' ], function( i, property ) {
            inc( me, property );
         });
      });
      cloned.insertAfter( last );
      if ( ! cloned.find( '.del_btn' ).length ) {
         cloned.append( 
            $( '<input class="del_btn"  type="button" value="Delete this">' )
               .css({"float":"right","background-color":"#c00","color":"#fff"})
         );
      }
      e.preventDefault();
   });

   $("body").on('click',".del_btn", function() { $(this).parent().remove(); });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="section-table-section-start1" data-id="section-start1" class="form-table form-table-section no-border form-table-section-indented">
   <tr>
      <th scope="row">
         <div class="xform_field_th">
            Block</div>
      </th>
      <td>
         <fieldset id="xform_demo-switch-fold-1" class=" xform-container-switch" data-id="switch-fold-1" data-type="switch">
            <div class="switch-options">
               <label class="cb-enable selected" data-id="switch-fold-1">
                  <span>On</span>
               </label>
               <label class="cb-disable" data-id="switch-fold-1">
                  <span>Off</span>
               </label>
               <input class="checkbox checkbox-input" id="switch-fold-1" name="xform_demo[switch-fold-1]" value="1" type="hidden"/>
            </div>
         </fieldset>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="fold">
      <th scope="row">
         <div class="xform_field_th">
            Text logo</div>
      </th>
      <td>
         <fieldset id="xform_demo-block-cat-title-1" class="xform-container-text " data-id="block-cat-title-1" data-type="text">
            <input id="block-cat-title-1" name="xform_demo[block-cat-title-1]" value class="regular-text " type="text" size="20"/>
         </fieldset>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="fold">
      <th scope="row">
         <div class="xform_field_th">
         </div>
      </th>
      <td>
         <fieldset id="xform_demo-block-post-order-1" class=" xform-container-select" data-id="block-post-order-1" data-type="select">
            <div style="width: 40%;" id="s2id_block-post-order-1-select" class="select2-container xform-select-item select2-allowclear">
               <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">
                  <span id="select2-chosen-2" class="select2-chosen">first-choise</span>
                  <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"/>
                  <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">
                     <b role="presentation">
                     </b>
                  </span>
               </a>
               <label for="s2id_autogen2" class="select2-offscreen">
               </label>
               <input id="s2id_autogen2" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-2" class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" type="text" size="20"/>
               <div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox">
                  <div class="select2-search">
                     <label for="s2id_autogen2_search" class="select2-offscreen"/>
                     <input placeholder id="s2id_autogen2_search" aria-owns="select2-results-2" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input"  type="text" size="20"/>
                  </div>
                  <ul id="select2-results-2" class="select2-results" role="listbox">
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
            <select title tabindex="-1" id="block-post-order-1-select" name="xform_demo[block-post-order-1]" class="xform-select-item " style="width: 40%; display: none;" rows="6">
               <option/>
               <option value="Desc" selected="selected">Lates</option>
               <option value="rand">Random Posts</option>
            </select>
         </fieldset>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="border-bottom: medium none;" class="compiler fold">
      <th scope="row">
         <div class="xform_field_th">
                        Block Style</div>
      </th>
      <td>
         <fieldset id="xform_demo-block_type_1" class=" xform-container-image_select" data-id="block_type_1" data-type="image_select">
            <div class="xform-table-container">
               <ul class="xform-image-select">
                  <li class="xform-image-select">
                     <label class=" xform-image-select-selected xform-image-select block_type_1_1" for="block_type_1_1">
                        <input class=" compiler noUpdate " id="block_type_1_1" name="xform_demo[block_type_1]" value="node" checked="checked" type="radio"/>
                        <img src="1-3.png" alt="node" class style=" width: 100%; "/>
                     </label>
                  </li>
                  <li class="xform-image-select">
                     <label class=" xform-image-select block_type_1_2" for="block_type_1_2">
                        <input class=" compiler noUpdate  noUpdate " id="block_type_1_2" name="xform_demo[block_type_1]" value="nodey" type="radio"/>
                        <img src="1-4.png" alt="nodey" class style=" width: 100%; "/>
                     </label>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </fieldset>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="display: none;" class="xform-section-indent-start">
      <th scope="row"/>
      <td/>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect code, But when remove any of fields number not decreased, How we can do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Before talking about a possible solution, I'll try to paraphrase to confirm that my understanding of the problem statement is correct...

1. You have some HTML that will be cloned to append on a container
2. A button will trigger append
3. Counter in multiple attributes on the cloned HTML must be incremented

Neither OP nor my suggested solution considers other common possible situations:

1. What must happen when an element is deleted:

   - Will the counters be recalculated?
   - Are gaps in counters allowed?
   - etc...

Anyway, now talking about the solution, I'll not use the code given in OP. Instead, I'll offer a general approach and leave actual implementation as a homework:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Container which will hold your elements -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- Original element, this block will be duplicated -->
    <div class="element">
        <input id="input1id" class="input1class" name="input1name" />
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="trigger">Append Copy</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // HTML to copy. Used an uncommon string (@@) as place holder for actual counter
        var elementCopy = '<div class="element">'+
'       <input id="input@@id" class="input@@class" name="input@@name" />'+
'   </div>';

        $('#trigger').on('click', function() {
            var count = $('.element').length;   // number of elements with class "element"
            var counter = count + 1;    // Counter to use for new element(s)
            var clone = elementCopy.replace(/\@\@/g, counter);      // Substitute counter for all @@ in elementCopy; note the 'g' switch (global) in regex
            $('.container').append(clone);  // Finally append new HTML
        })
    });
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uc4mda2h/).